# Java NativeKeyListener finished with exit code 0

Tags: java, jnativehook

I am trying to make a program that can detect my key strokes then based on them do something but every time I run my program it just finishes with exit code 0 even though I have the listeners initialized any ideas? (I got no errors)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InitializeEvents initializeEvents = new InitializeEvents();
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(initializeEvents.getKeyboard());
        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeMouseListener(initializeEvents.getMouse());
       }
    }
```

Here is where I initialize my event

```
    public class InitializeEvents {
       private final NativeKeyboardEvent keyboard;
       private final NativeMouseClickEvent mouse;

       public InitializeEvents() {
           keyboard = new NativeKeyboardEvent();
           mouse = new NativeMouseClickEvent();
       }

       public NativeKeyboardEvent getKeyboard() {
           return keyboard;
       }

       public NativeMouseClickEvent getMouse() {
           return mouse;
       }
    }
```

Lastly here is my event

```
    public class NativeKeyboardEvent implements NativeKeyListener {
    
       @Override
       public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
           System.out.println("test");
       }

       @Override
       public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
           System.out.println("test");
       }

       @Override
       public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
           System.out.println("test");
       }
    }
```

The weird thing about it is that it was working earlier but then it  randomly stopped printing "test" when I clicked a key even though nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as your application no longer has any non-daemon threads running, it will terminate. You can easily validate this by putting

```java
while(true) {
    Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

on the last line in your `main` method. Eventually, I can imagine that your application will either have an active window or a taskbar icon that keeps it alive and that adds an application quit option, replacing the need for this temporary solution.

Comment: Ok but while testing inside my IDE I should use keep the thread sleeping? Thank you for the solution I will try it out.

Comment: Technically it does not care what you do, as long as a non-daemon thread is still alive. Sleeping is just a very easy task on the CPU, whereas an empty endless loop would cost more computation power.